# How to change the data of a table field from another?

Tags: python, django

Good evening.
The goal is that when creating the **Transfer** model, the **sum** field was subtracted from **whom_from** and added to **whom_to**  Bill's model. As I understand it, this needs to be done through save (), but apparently, I did not set it up correctly. What could be the problem?

models.py

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, 
                                 validators=[MinValueValidator(0)], default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Transfer(models.Model):
    whom_from = models.ForeignKey(Bill, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='whom_from')
    whom_to = models.ForeignKey(Bill, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='whom_to')
    sum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)], default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.whom_to.amount = self.whom_to.amount + self.sum
        self.whom_from.amount = self.whom_from.amount - self.sum
        super(Transfer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You need to save whom_to and whom_from after changing their data.

Comment: @DanielRoseman How to do it?

Comment: Er, call `self.whom_to.save()`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you)